# Prevent flex PARENT from growing without overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Too much information how to prevent flex child from growing, but too difficult to find out how to prevent flex PARENT from growing (because of the child).

Consider below layout:

- The outer element's height and width are fixed (possible for native applications)
- Header and footer are not growing and not shrink. Also, footer is always at the bottom.
- Main content (between header and footer) takes all available space.
- Main content has NOT scrolling.

  - But the inner elements could be scrolled. E. g. the scroll view below section title:

[image]

Initial solution:

```css
.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 640px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.2);
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.2);
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: rgba(255, 69, 0, 0.2);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.title {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.splitView {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.2);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.splitView-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.splitView-section:first-child {
  background: rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.2);
}

.splitView-section:last-child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

.scrollView {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.2);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.veryBigElement {
  background: #CD5C5C;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0 0 6px
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background: rgba(173, 255, 47, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="header">I am header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="splitView">
      <div class="splitView-section">
        <div class="sectionTitle">Section title</div>
        <div class="scrollView">
          <div class="veryBigElement"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="splitView-section"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">I am footer</div>
</div>
```

- *The outer element's height and width are fixed*: let it will be `width: 640px` and `height: 300px;` for instance.
- *Header and footer are not grow and not shrink.* `flex: 0 0 auto` for header and footer.
- *Main content (between header and footer) takes all available space.* `flex: 1 1 auto`.
- *Also footer is always in the bottom.* Footer does not need `margin-top: auto` because it is being pressed to bottom by main content.
- *Main content has NOT scrolling.* It will not by default.
- *But the inner elements could be scrolled.* `overflow-y: auto` for scroll view.

It works. But there is one problem: if we add some elements with shadows (e. g. cards to scroll view), because of `overflow-y: hidden` for `.splitView` and `.content`, we will not see the part of it. E. g. if to add `box-shadow: rgba(black, 0.25) 0 0 6px` for `.veryBigElement`, we see just:

[image]

So, in dependence to design, above solution may not be used. If we remove `overflow-y: hidden` from `.splitView` and `.content`, `splitView-section` will grow regardless to `overflow-y: auto` for `.scrollView`.

**Please not that:**

- We don't know neither header's height nor footers's height (suppose it's contents is dynamic).
- We can not compute `.scrollView`'s height, even `splitView`'s height: it could be a lot of contents instead of '.title' in real application.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/teyqkrh8/

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the box-shadow? It seems pretty normal. Is it because it's not seen on other elements? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Salix, the problem is: we see just right shadow of red rectangle, but want to see all four-side shadows.

Comment: And you want that shadow to go over the other sections?

Comment: Does the 'section title' grow? or is always same height?

Comment: @Salix, 'section title' must not grow - it must take it's natural height. "And you want that shadow to go over the other sections" - Yes.

Comment: By putting 'scrollView' in an other container you can us that container to position and give the height of an ':after' element on the veryBigElement. See updated codepen in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove "overflow-y: hidden" and add "height: 100%" to .splitView and -section.

```
.splitView{
    display: flex
    flex: 1 1 auto
    background: rgba(#008080, 0.2)
    height: 100%
    &-section{  
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        flex: 1 1 50%
        height: 100%
    }
}
```

Since the height of the parent div is set, the children divs will inherit that height.

https://codepen.io/salixdubois/pen/JQLaRE

Comment: Is was close to solution what I searched. Thank you for the answer. However, you did not mentioned in answer what because of `overflow-y: auto;` shadow will be still cut off. It looks like there is no intuitive solution. Only padding or negative margin can solve this problem.

Comment: Yes. But that's normal and not because of overflow-y: auto. It's actually because you want the height to be the same as the parent's so the parent doesn't grow. If it can't be higher, it can't overflow and thus the shadow can't go over. But for cards, padding is usual. If you really want the shadow to go over the parent, you could proably make it so with an :after or something.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but anyway would be useful for others.

Since you don't want to apply some padding to outer container or margin to the shadowed element, you can simply give z-index (greater than any outer elements z-index (if set of course)) property to the shadowed element and it will override cutoffs.

Comment: Good solution! Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you gave the "**veryBigElement**" height 500px and you want main content will not be scrolling only inner elements could be scrolled. So you have to add **MAX-HEIGHT** of veryBigElement **parent**. If you remove the overflow-y: hidden than splitView-section will not grow.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Unfortunately, we need to calculate this max-height using pre-processors. As far as layout more complicated, it will be difficult to do it.